# Выборка нескольких записей с разными данными из одной таблицы

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Проблема такая:
Есть таблица staff, в которой хранятся учётные записи сотрудников

`id | login | pass`
`-----------------`
`1  |  usr  | 1234`

И таблица c переводами (lang_ru, lang_en, etc) различных записей, где в item_id  записан id c таблицы, которая указана в table_name, к которой этот перевод относится. 
В item_destination - указано поле, которое переводится.
В item_text - сам перевод

`id | item_id | table_name | item_destination | item_text`
`--------------------------------------------------------`
`1  |   1     |   staff    |     name         | Василий`
`2  |   1     |   staff    |     position     | Охранник`

Можно ли в MySQL  каким-то образом одним запросом выбрать запись из таблицы staff и все связанные с ней записи из таблицы с переводами?
Моих знаний хватает только на простой Join который вернёт мне пару Строка из staff -> Строка из lang, и на одну запись из staff выведет две из lang.
Здравый смысл подсказывает, что так сделать нельзя, но вдруг есть что-то, о чём я еще не успел узнать в процессе обучения
Структура таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `login` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `pass` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `seed` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `access_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_registered` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `photo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `lang_ru` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `table_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `item_destination` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Если не сложно, напишите что хотите получить. SQL - это таблицы, на входе одна или несколько таблиц, на выходе - одна таблица. Что хотите видеть в результирующей таблице?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите структуру исходных таблиц. Для этого необходимо выполнить запрос
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name, где table_name заменить на имя таблицы.

Comment: Хочу получить таблицу приблизительно следующей структуры  id(из таблицы staff) | login | name | position что бы потом эти поля использовать в выводе на странице

Comment: Вы можете конечно сделать свой join, дополнительно дать group by staff.id что бы получить одну строку и использовать функцию group_concat(item_destination) которая вернет вам все значения через запятую в одной колонке. а вообще обычно получают обычным join и собирают данные в горизонталь уже на клиенте. потому как sql в принципе не предназначен для выборки неопределенного на момент написания запроса количества колонок